# Powershell ConvertTo-Json from CSV

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I need some help with converting a CSV File to Json using PowerShell. I have a script that gets the send message logs from Office365 using PowerShell and export them into a CSV file. I will then use the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet to Convert the CSV file into Json. The output Json file includes so many unnecessary texts that make it hard to read. For example, here is what I want:

```
{
 "SenderAddress":  "support@email.com",
 "RecipientAddress":  "zzzz@email.edu",
 "Subject":  "Microsoft PowerShell",
 "Status":  "Delivered",
 }
```

Here is what I get after converting the CSV to Json:

```
{
        "value":  "\"support@email.com\",\"zzzz@email.edu\",\"Microsoft PowerShell\",\"Delivered\"",
        "PSPath":  "C:\\Logs\\Logs-1.csv",
        "PSParentPath":  "C:\\Logs",
        "PSChildName":  "Logs-1.csv",
        "PSDrive":  {
                        "CurrentLocation":  "Windows\\system32",
                        "Name":  "C",
                        "Provider":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\\FileSystem",
                        "Root":  "C:\\",
                        "Description":  "Windows",
                        "MaximumSize":  null,
                        "Credential":  "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential",
                        "DisplayRoot":  null
                    },
        "PSProvider":  {
                           "ImplementingType":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider",
                           "HelpFile":  "System.Management.Automation.dll-Help.xml",
                           "Name":  "FileSystem",
                           "PSSnapIn":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
                           "ModuleName":  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core",
                           "Module":  null,
                           "Description":  "",
                           "Capabilities":  52,
                           "Home":  "C:\\Users\\test",
                           "Drives":  "C D E"
                       },
        "ReadCount":  3
```

Here is the PowerShell cmdlet I run to convert the CSV file to Json.

```
Get-Content "C:\Logs\logs-1.csv" | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "C:\Logs\logs-1.json
```

I also tried the following:

```
Get-Content "C:\Logs\logs-1.csv" |Select-Object -Property SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, Subject, Status ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "C:\Logs\logs-1.json
```

I go this result:

```
{
    "SenderAddress":  null,
    "RecipientAddress":  null,
    "Subject":  null,
    "Status":  null
}
```

Any idea what I can do to convert the CSV file to Json correctly without the extra info?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the CSV log file, including header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to use `Import-Csv` not `Get-Content` or `Get-Item`.

Try:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Logs\logs-1.csv" |
    ConvertTo-Json |
    Add-Content -Path "C:\Logs\logs-1.json"
```

Or:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Logs\logs-1.csv" |
    Select-Object -Property SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, Subject, Status |
    ConvertTo-Json |
    Add-Content -Path "C:\Logs\logs-1.json"
```

If you intend to overwrite `C:\Logs\logs-1.json`, use `Set-Content` instead of `Add-Content`.

Comment: Thank you! switching Get-Content to Import-CSV did the trick. I did not know it was that simple.

Comment: As a side note, you can also read CSV from a string using `ConvertFrom-CSV`. This can be useful, for example, when the CSV is grabbed from remote resource

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could define how many levels of contained objects are included in the JSON representation (default depth = 2).

```
import-csv .\INPUTFILE.csv | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File .\OUTPUTFILE.json
```